# What's the difference between line breaks in template literals and '\' in string literals?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading about template literals in the ES2015 spec which allows you to create (among other things) line breaks like so:

```
var brokenStr = `This is
    a broken
    string.`; //This is a broken string
```

We can also break a string literal with the backslash `\` character.

```
var anotherBrokenStr = 'This is \
    also a broken \
    string.'; //This is also a broken string.
```

Is there a performance difference between the two? Which is considered best practice?

I have searched SO.

**Update:**

When I output as follows, I get a single line.

```
document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML = brokenStr;
```

When I use `document.write()` I get this in Chrome inspector:

> ```
> This is     also a broken     string.
> ```

Which colapses the whitespace to a single space in the browser/

**Update: Update:**

It appears that the template literal includes a `\n` character. Then, is there any difference between the first example and this, or is it just syntax sugar?

```
var anotherBrokenStr = 'This is \\n
    also a broken \\n
    string.';
```

Comment: In the first case you'd get line breaks in your string. In the second case you wouldn't get any line breaks. It's just a way to continue the string on the next line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings

Comment: If you're worried about performance then don't be. Thinking about performance in this case is a [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: One inserts new lines, the other explicitly doesn't. They aren't the same thing, so comparing their performance makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks guys! Why does my browser input it as a single line then? `document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML = brokenStr;`

Comment: HTML does not respect the newline character .. inspect the string in the console and you will see it differently

Comment: @AaditMShah there is also [this handy chart](https://xkcd.com/1691/) one can use to determine if they are prematurely optimising.

Comment: @AaditMShah I suppose the optimization part is null... I am interested in the differences though.

Comment: @littlewolf it's been repeatedly stated - first one has new lines, the second one doesn't. What other difference are you looking for?

Comment: When does `\n` respect the newline then?

Comment: and  if the template parses to that? Why is it invalid? This is confusing me more...

Comment: @littlewolf if you print it in the console. If you put it in a text area. In a `<pre>` tag...

Comment: I think my misunderstanding traces back to how HTML is rendered rather than the JS. Thanks, I'm marking this as answered.

Comment: Indeed. You finally got it. I updated my answer to explain the concept to you but it seems like that won't be necessary now.

Comment: @AaditMShah It may help other users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the output of my Node.js REPL showing the difference between the two:

```js
> `hello
... world`
'hello\nworld'
> 'hello\
... world'
'helloworld'
```

In the first case we get a newline between `'hello'` and `'world'`. In the second case we don't.

---

**Edit:** Dear Lord, you're thoroughly confused.

```html
HTML doesn't

respect newlines.


It doesn't matter how many newlines



you put in between your lines.




HTML will still print it





as a single line.
```

Hope that makes things clear.

Comment: In the example above there is a whitespace before the backslash character `hello \ ` although, why is Node adding a `\n`? It should output to a single unbroken line. It does in my browser...

Comment: @littlewolf: The template literal literally contains line breaks. What browser are you using? Chrome clearly shows the line breaks (not encoded but literally).

Comment: @FelixKling I am using Chrome and outputting to HTML (see comment in op)

Comment: @littlewolf: HTML ignores line breaks (treats them as spaces). https://jsfiddle.net/fcp1st3j/